# Equiv string maps (unordered type) to equal string

Tags: string, maps, unordered-map, coq

I want to prove that if string maps (key*value) are Equiv, then the string lists are equal OR 
convert two Equiv maps to equal strings of key-value pairs.

```
(**defined in FMapInterface*)
Definition Equiv (eq_elt:elt->elt->Prop) m m' :=
         (forall k, In k m <-> In k m') /\
         (forall k e e', MapsTo k e m -> MapsTo k e' m' -> eq_elt e e').

Definition t (elt:Set) := list (X.t * elt) (**defined in FMapWeakList *).
```

In my case, X.t and elt are String.string (string map).

```
Definition StringMap_to_strlist (zm : t String.string) : String.string :=
   fold (fun k v z => (k ++ v) ::  z) zm "". 


Lemma test: forall m m, 
       Equiv m m -> StringMap_to_strlist m = StringMap_to_strlist m.
```

For example, for two Equiv string maps m and m',

```
 m    quiv   m'
 k1:v1       k1:v1
 k3:v1       k2:v2
 k2:v2       k3:v1
```

The correspong lists may be like:
 `k1++v1::k3++v1::k2++v2  and k1++v1::k2++v2::k3++v1` which are not equal.

I want to prove that if maps are Equiv, then the string lists are equal OR 
convert two Equiv maps to equal strings of key-value pairs. 
In my case, the order of key-value pairs in the string is not imporant, 
so ordering the list is ok, if possible. For the maps, the following list is 
acceptable in my case.

```
k1++v1::k2++v2::k3++v1 = k1++v1::k2++v2::k3++v1
```

I dont know how
 to convert Equiv (unordered type) string maps to equal strings. 
 Please some one help me